# Exploding memory consumption when training FL model with varying number of participants per round

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm running FL algorithm following the [image classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) tutorial. The number of participants vary at each round according to a predefined list of participants number.

```py
number_of_participants_each_round = 
[108, 113, 93, 92, 114, 101, 94, 93, 107, 99, 118, 101, 114, 111, 88, 
101, 86, 96, 110, 80, 118, 84, 91, 120, 110, 109, 113, 96, 112, 107, 
119, 91, 97, 99, 97, 104, 103, 120, 89, 100, 104, 104, 103, 88, 108]
```

The federated data is preprocessed and batched before starting the training.

```py
NUM_EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 20
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 418
PREFETCH_BUFFER = 10

def preprocess(dataset):
    def batch_format_fn(element):
        return collections.OrderedDict(
            x=tf.reshape(element['pixels'], [-1, 784]),
            y=tf.reshape(element['label'], [-1, 1]))

    return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER).batch(
        BATCH_SIZE).map(batch_format_fn).prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER)


def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
    return [preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x)) for x in client_ids]

federated_train_data = make_federated_data(data_train, data_train.client_ids)
```

Participants are randomly sampled from `federated_train_data[0:expected_total_clients]` at each round according to the `number_of_participants_each_round`, then the `iterative_process` is executed for `45 rounds`.

```py
expected_total_clients = 500
round_nums = 45

for round_num in range(0, round_nums):
   sampled_clients = 
       np.random.choice(a=federated_train_data[0:expected_total_clients],                          
                        size=number_of_participants_each_round[round_num], 
                        replace=False)
    
   state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, list(sampled_clients))
   print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num + 1, metrics))
```

The problem is that the `VRAM` usage quickly explodes after few rounds, it reaches `5.5 GB` at round `6~7`, and keeps increasing with an approx rate of `0.8 GB/round` until the training eventually crashes at round `25~26` where the VRAM reaches `17 GB` with `+4000` python threads created.

Error message below

```py
F tensorflow/core/platform/default/env.cc:72] Check failed: ret == 0 (35 vs. 0)Thread creation via pthread_create() failed.
```

**### Troubleshooting ###**

Reducing the `number_of_participants_each_round` to `20` allows the training to complete, but the memory consumption was still huge and growing.

Running the same code with fixed number of participants per round, memory consumption was fine with total of approx `1.5 ~ 2.0 GB` VRAM throughout the entire training.

```py
expected_total_clients = 500
fixed_client_size_per_round = 100
round_nums = 45

for round_num in range(0, round_nums):
   sampled_clients =
      np.random.choice(a=federated_train_data[0:expected_total_clients],
                       size=fixed_client_size_per_round,
                       replace=False)
    
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, list(sampled_clients))
    print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num + 1, metrics))
```

Extra details:

```
OS: MacOS Mojave, 10.14.6
python -V: Python 3.8.5 then downgraded to Python 3.7.9
TF version: 2.4.1
TFF version: 0.18.0
Keras version: 2.4.3
```

Is this a normal memory behaviour or a `bug`? Are there any refactoring/hints to optimize memory consumption ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a bug in the `executor stack` of the TFF runtime process.

Complete details and bug fix below

https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/1215